# Any possible ways to use my iPhone presence in wifi network as a trigger?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, triggers, wifi

My goal is to record the time when I am out/arrive home, and certain calendar event. I know how to do everything except finding out the triggers that will indicate that I am at home.

**Alternative #1**
I think using my iPhone presence in my Wifi network is one of the best alternative that came to my mind. But I don't know any possible ways how I can achieve it through iOS, or osx.

**Alternative #2**
I also was thinking about using IFTTT on iPhone (Locator + Google Calendar), but it will decrease battery usage.

Do you know how to achieve wifi detection of my phone. Or maybe there are other ideas what could be used as a trigger?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using geofencing?

Comment: @rmaddy, It is not just programming question. It is more about how to use something as trigger. If you know any programming solution, than please share with us.

Comment: @Curmudgeonlybumbly, as I mentioned in the details, monitoring gps coordinates would require significant battery usage, which make this option less attractive.

Comment: @Somew I asked because this site is for programming questions and this doesn't appear to be a programming question. You should probably ask this on a more appropriate site.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't looked into this much yet, but instead of running IFTTT on your phone, you can now have it on your (Google) router:

http://thenextweb.com/gadgets/2016/04/28/googles-onhub-router-ifttt/

Answer (score 0):

iOS has built in support for geofence-based regions, which use a mixture of GPS, WiFi, accelerometer, and other sensors. An OS based geofence will even launch your program in order to notify it that you have entered/exited the region. It's also designed to be power-efficient. Take a look at the location manager and `CLCircularRegion`.